# How to apply region segmentation on data that is NOT image?

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, scientific-computing, hierarchical-clustering

I have a dataset with the following features:

[latitude, longitude, income]

I want to detect regions of homogeneous average income (off course, the algorithm must be robust so that the a region might contain one or other outlier).

In the following case, the more blue the point, the higher the income, I want to detect these regions (some sort of clustering/segmentation algorithm):

[image]

At the time I'm using python and sklearn, if the solution uses any any of those

Comment: It boils down to proper math. Define what a region is. Is a region generally defined by a set of coordinates? Then what you observe actually is an image, but it's not yet in cartesian form.

Comment: but I assume that an image would not have that many "blanks". Imagine a matrix 1000x1000 where I only have 1000 properties (pixels).

Comment: Depends; I'd totally say that is ok; if you want so, you could low-pass filter the 1000x1000 image and scale it (decimate it, I'm a signal processing guy) e.g. to 50x50